# Codeigniter Email Headers

Tags: php, email, codeigniter

Hi I got this email headers when testing emails using codeigniter. I use the mail function for sending emails like registration and password resets. The thing is it displays server paths which may compromise my server.

How can I remove these headers in the email?

```
X-AntiAbuse:     This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse:     Primary Hostname - example.example.com
X-AntiAbuse:     Original Domain - yahoo.com
X-AntiAbuse:     Originator/Caller UID/GID - [666 32003] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse:     Sender Address Domain - example.com
X-Source:       /usr/bin/php
X-Source-Args:   /usr/bin/php /home/public_html/codeigniter_path/index.php
X-Source-Dir:    domain.com:/public_html/codeigniter_path
```

Comment: you got some serious issues, if exposing a server path compromises security, some ore all of that may be being added by your hosts mail server, send an email with out codeigniter to check

Comment: That's part of the mail server configuration then. Contact your hoster.

Comment: got roundcube in my server and it also produces these headers.. got to contact my host then.. thanks!

Comment: they are adding them to make sure *you* don't spam people, or if you do they can track you, there is no security issue with providing the server path.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be confident in saying this is nothing to do with CodeIgniter.

Your hosts look like they are modifying all outgoing mail with extra headers to try and stop their servers getting blacklisted by spammers, or to try and reduce the chances of your emails being marked as spam.

Either way their solution is invasive and a bit weird but not insecure. If it bugs you then I'd change to using an external SMTP provider like Google, or just get a better host.

Answer (score 0):

I have **100% solution for disable X-AntiAbuse and X-Get-Message-Sender**.

Step 1: Login **as ROOT** with **PuTTY**

Step 2: type **nano /etc/exim.pl.local**

Step 3: Press Enter, After open **exim.pl.local** file. Click CTRL+W for search.

Step 4: Type "Abuse" and press enter to search.

Step 5: Then you can see X-AntiAbuse Headers like below..

Step 6: Just **add a line above** "my $headers = " like bellow and **change old** "my $headers = .." to "my $headers_clear = .."

Change and Add like below

**my $headers = "";**

**my $headers_clear =**

Demo: http://snag.gy/cketX.jpg

Step 7: After done, above like, **Press CTRL+X** for save and Press **"Y"** for Confirm after finally **press "Enter"** for Save and Exit.

Now, Try a Test Email. Where **No X-AntiAbuse** and **X-Get-Message-Sender Headers.**